# Select top first row for each group based on multiple order criterias

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Disclaimer: I have searched for similar questions but I haven't found a clear answer to my issue.

I have a table like this:

```
id | catid | views | text
1    100      2000   "sometext"
2    200      2000   "sometext"
3    200      3000   "longertext"
```

For each catid (that in this case are just 2: 100 and 200) i need to get the record with the most views and the longer texts... In this case the result would be:

```
id | catid | views | text
1    100      2000   "sometext"
3    200      3000   "longertext"
```

With priority on the number of views.
I have tried some queries with inner joins but none seems clear and working...

Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Strawberry: The answer below is much better than the answer found in your linked question !

Comment: I'm sure they're essentially the same

Comment: Here's a nested `JOIN` solution to give the result you want: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rTwJKMNjoG5KUe8pSU36Su/0

Comment: @Nick: that's much more complex than the simple GMB query. Regarding the efficiency: in this case future maintanability is preferred over efficiency since this is a one shot query

Comment: @giò it looks more complex, but there are a total of 3 selects in that query, whereas for GMBs answer there is 1 select for *every* row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method uses a correlated subquery with `order by` and `limit` for filtering. Assuming that `id` is primary or unique key:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (
    select id 
    from mytable t1
    where t1.catid = t.catid
    order by t1.views desc, char_length(t1.text) desc
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: Spectacular query: simple and effective... I haven't found this query in the other related questions. I hope this aswer will popup earlier in the google searches

Comment: @giò because the subquery has to be executed for *every* row I think you'll find this is a *lot* less efficient than the queries in the linked question when your table gets large.